# Combine N number of videos in React Native using ffmpeg-kit-react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate N videos in one video.
I already tried many libraries, but without any success. The libraries I tried are:

[react-native-video-processor](https://github.com/salihgun/react-native-video-processor)

[react-native-video-merger](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/react-native-video-merger)

[react-native-video-manager](https://github.com/lklima/react-native-video-manager/)

[ffmpeg-kit-react-native](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit)

None of them are working in the way I need, and can't find any specific commands to merge videos without the need of audio.

I also tried these commands:

```
`-i ${videoPaths.join(' -i ')} -filter_complex concat=n=${videoPaths.length}:v=1:a=0 [v] -map [v] -vf "scale=w=720:h=trunc(ow/a/2)*2,setsar=1:1" -c:v libx264 -c:a none -shortest -y ${outputVideoPath}`;

`-i ${videoPaths.join(' -i ')} -filter_complex concat=n=${videoPaths.length}:v=1:a=0 -strict -2 ${outputVideoPath}`;
```

But nothing is working in the way I need.

Comment: Why did any of those libraries work? Is it an error message, or they require audio, and you don't want audio on your video?

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like, you want to merge videos that don't have audio.

As said on [this](https://github.com/MostWantIT/react-native-video-editor/issues/6) issue on the react-native-video-editor, you can edit some lines of code on the library, so it does not process audio while merging the video, so it would fit your needs.

The files and lines you need to comment (or remove) are:

File `node_modules/react-native-video-editor/ios/RNVideoEditor.m`, lines 42 and 43:

```objectivec
AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
```

File `node_modules/react-native-video-editor/ios/RNVideoEditor.m`, lines 60 to 63:

```objectivec
[audioTrack insertTimeRange:timeRange
ofTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]
atTime:insertTime
error:nil];
```

You can fork the [react-native-video-editor](https://github.com/MostWantIT/react-native-video-editor) repository, make these changes and save it, so you can install from your repository instead of the official repository (if you have a GitHub account, of course). If you don't do this, you will need to edit these files on your `node_modules` every time you install the package.

If you need to do it on Android too, I suppose you need to comment/remove these lines (I can't test this, but as I read on the code, this should work):

File `react-native-video-editor/android/src/main/java/com/reactlibrary/RNVideoEditorModule.java`, lines 53, lines 57 to 59, lines 78 to 75:

```java
[...]
List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
[...]

[...]
if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
  audioTracks.add(t);
}
[...]

[...]
if (!audioTracks.isEmpty()) {
  try {
    result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
[...]
```

Comment: Okay will look it Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I ended up with the sample code on the React Native Android end

```
`-y -i video_one.mp4 -i video_two.mp4 -filter_complex \
  "[0:v] scale=720:1280,setsar=1[v0]; [1:v] scale=720:1280,setsar=1[v1]; \
  [v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -strict -2 output.mp4`
```

By using the below NPM

```
ffmpeg-kit-react-native
```